# How to run GUI on ubuntu server and access it from Ununtu or Windows using private key

Tags: 20.04, windows, gui, remote-desktop, xrdp

I have oracle instance with ubuntu as a OS. Now I want to install GUI onto ubuntu and access it from my laptop (Ubuntu or Windows).

I know how to install GUI on Ubuntu but how do I access it. When I generated Oracle instance I received a private key file and that I have stored it with my. I am able to ssh using private key but how to access GUI using that.

When I use Remote Desktop Client in Windows(have insalled xrdp also) it asks for Id and password to connect to my server. I have created another userid and password also but still I am not able to access GUI.

Comment: Sorry, I tagged wrong version. My ubuntu server is running 20.04

Comment: Ubuntu has GUI by default, there is no need to install or run anything.